# Adding AJAX to drupal commerce checkout pane

Tags: commerce, ajax

I need to add dependable fields to Drupal Commerce checkout. I wrote my own module to do this but AJAX seems to not work.
Here is the code of my module:

```
function moje_panele_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state) {
  //parent item
  $form['sposob_dostawy'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Wybierz sposób dostawy'),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('Kurier'),
      1 => t('Odbiór osobisty'),
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'my_checkout_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'dane-do-odbioru',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );
  //child markup
  $form['dane_do_odbioru'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Dane do odbioru"),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dane-do-odbioru">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'markup',
  );
  //dependent field
  if ($form_state['values']['moje_panele_pane']['sposob_dostawy'] == 1) {
    $form['dane_do_odbioru'] = array(
      '#title' => t("Dane do odbioru"),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="dane-do-odbioru">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
    );
    $form['dane_do_odbioru']['imie'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield', 
      '#title' => t('Imię'), 
      '#size' => 60, 
      '#maxlength' => 128, 
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
  return $form;
}

//my AJAX callback
function my_checkout_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['dane_do_odbioru'];
}
```

The above code works fine on normal Drupal page, but I cannot make it work on checkout page as a pane.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using [`hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info/DC)? 

Have a look at this module for an example of AJAX on a checkout pane, in this case, an altered account pane: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_login

Comment: Yes, I'm using this hook. Is there any option to add AJAX to my custom pane? I need to ask customers for many informations and I'd like to use AJAX, since I'm using 1 page checkout.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might have to be related with the classes on the checkout form, if you check the [commerce shipping](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) module - it has a good ajax example on replacements - you can see how it does:

```
// Add a radios element to let the customer select a shipping service.
$pane_form['shipping_service'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'commerce_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh',
    'wrapper' => 'commerce-shipping-service-details',
  ),
);
```

And then it forces the class with a prefix:

```
$pane_form['service_details']['#prefix'] = '<div id="commerce-shipping-service-details">';
$pane_form['service_details']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

The ajax callback is the usual one:

```
/**
 * Ajax callback: Returns the shipping details form elements that match the
 * currently selected shipping service.
 */
function commerce_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['commerce_shipping']['service_details'];
}
```

So definitely possible, check the css classes you're dealing with.